# Can someone explain to me a few thing about this JQuery code I have here from the MVC Music Store tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

The thing that confuses me somewhat and it's probably due to the conventions in
the jquery ajax() request .post() function is that it does not indicate anywhere that if request is successful that it should call the handleUpdate() function which gets the returned json object via "var json = context.get_data();", also why is the whole chunk of code starting with "if (data.ItemCount == 0)" in the handleUpdate() identical to the one in the .post() on success run > function (data) { duplicate code } .

Maybe because function (data) {} is callback function it waits for the entire request/response cycle to finish and that includes  "var json = context.get_data();" in handleUpdate() ?

Thanks..

Pasted from the tutorial PDF, no other jscript in this view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '')
            {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": recordToDelete },
                function (data) {
                // Successful requests get here
                // Update the page elements
                if (data.ItemCount == 0)
                {
                    $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                }

                $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                });
            }
        });
    });

    function handleUpdate()
    {
        // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
        var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

        // Update the page elements
        if (data.ItemCount == 0)
        {
            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
        }

        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There must be some server side code that does something like `RegisterClientCallback('handleUpdate');`. Otherwise it doesn't make sense. I think the server is supposed to push data out periodically and binds the handleUpdate to that pushing somewhere in some magic.

Comment: The tutorial states: The RemoveFromCart returns a JSON serialized result, which is automatically passed to the JavaScript method specified in our AjaxOptions OnSuccess parameter – handleUpdate in this case. The handleUpdate Javascript function parses the JSON results and performs four quick updates to the page using jQuery. I don't see this OnSuccess parameter anywhere though!

Comment: the onsuccess parameter is not in the code. Either the code is _wrong_ or there is more code somewhere in the pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handleUpdate() function is a relic from the previous [MVC2](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/53639) version of the tutorial where the Ajax for removing items from the cart was handled by Microsoft's Ajax called via an Ajax.ActionLink helper. (see below)

This was changed to use JQuery Ajax in the [MVC3](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) version of this tutorial but the handleUpdate() code has been left in it seems by mistake during the conversion from MVC2 to MVC3.

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleUpdate(context) {
        // Load and deserialize the returned JSON data
        var json = context.get_data();
        var data = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(json);

        // Update the page elements
        $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
    }
</script>
```

...

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Remove from cart", "RemoveFromCart", 
         new { id = item.RecordId }, 
         new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "handleUpdate" })%>
```

Comment: Thanks, dang why did they do this! It's suppose to be a tutorial that makes straightforward, clean examples not derail and confuse the hell out of people. I think I have found more left over/useless code this times on the server side in the ShoppingCart class. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (according to this code) that `handleUpdate` is being called on success of `$.post`. Jquery post function has following syntax

```
$.post(url,data, callback);
```

and in the code you can see that all three parameters are explicitly specified and callback is an anonymous function with signature

```
function(data){}
```

Now, what you can see is that this anonymous function and handleUpdate are doing exactly the same logic. That makes me believe that they belong to the two different scenarios. For example, first scenario is that links are rendered using

```
Html.ActionLink(LinkText, ActionName, new{@class = "RemoveLink"})
```

In this case click event is handled by jquery function on the top and all the logic is done in this function (including ajax and callback). Second function might have been used for some

```
//please confirm all parameters of the function
Ajax.ActionLink(LinkText, ActionName, new AjaxOptions{onSuccess = "handleUpdate"});
```

and this seems to be connected with microsoftmvc ajax files that that used to exist in ancient times. You can put alert in each function and check what is the case with you.

Comment: Strange there is not OnSuccess or AjaxOptions statement anywhere in the code. see for yourself: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-8

Comment: in index.cshtml you can see `<a href="#" class="RemoveLink" data-id="@item.RecordId">Remove from cart</a>` it means that jquery click event handler is called. i got few errors with sql ce. you can check it by commenting out handleUPdate function. i believe everything will work fine without it